# How to retain some key value pairs of a List[T] in scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have a List[T] where the datas inside are like below:

```
[0]- id : "abc", name: "xyz", others: "value"
[1]- id : "bcd", name: "dsf", others: "value"
```

Now I want to return the same List[T] but with the id and names i.e the returning List will be:

```
[0]- id : "abc", name: "xyz"
[1]- id : "bcd", name: "dsf"
```

I tried with below code:

```
var temps = templates.map(x => List("id" -> x.id, "name" -> x.name))
```

But it it produces List inside List i.e:

```
[0]-
  [0] id : "abc"
  [1] name: "xyz"
[1]- 
  [0] id : "bcd"
  [1] name: "dsf"
```

***I tried with tuple also but in vain. How can i just map my list such that everything is cleaned out except the id and name value pair??***

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to define a new class with just the `id` and `name` fields, I think tuples would be your best bet:

```
scala> case class obj(id: String, name: String, others: String)
defined class obj

scala> val l = List(new obj("abc", "xyz", "value"), new obj("bcd", "dsf", "value"))
l: List[obj] = List(obj(abc,xyz,value), obj(bcd,dsf,value))

scala> l.map(x => (x.id, x.name))
res0: List[(String, String)] = List((abc,xyz), (bcd,dsf))
```

Also you are actually using tuples in your example, the `->` syntax creates tuples in Scala:

```
scala> "a" -> "b"
res1: (String, String) = (a,b)
```

Here is the "define another class" option:

```
scala> case class obj2(id: String, name: String){
     | def this(other: obj) = this(other.id, other.name)
     | }
defined class obj2

scala> l.map(new obj2(_))
res2: List[obj2] = List(obj2(abc,xyz), obj2(bcd,dsf))
```

Comment: Is there any way without the case class obj ??

Comment: I just added that for illustrative purposes. If you want to get properties from an object using the `.` operator (like you did for `x.id`)  you will need to have a class defined with that field.

Comment: I guess it kinda sounds like you are talking about a `Map`? Is [this](http://pastebin.com/YTtdb8Tz) what you are trying to do? If so it is not very Scala-stic, it would be best to explicitly define your fields in a `case class` rather than letting anyone throw things into a map.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `List[T]` is a `List[Map]`, then you may able to do the following:

```
//Remove the "others" key.
val temps = templates.map( map => {map - "others"})
```

Comment: Or just: `templates.map(_ - "others")`

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty clear that your list contains objects with three members: id, name, others. Hence you access them by using

> {x => x.name}

What I am not so sure about, is how you imagine your end result. You obviously need some data structure, that holds the members. 
You realized yourself, that its not very nice to store each objects members in a list inside the new list, but you seem to not be ok with tuples?

I can imagine, that tuples are just what you want.

```
val newList = oldList.map{e => e.id -> e.name}
```

results in alist like this:

> List(("id_a", "name_a"), ("id_b", "name_b"), ("id_c","name_c"))

and can be accessed like this(for example):

```
newList.head._1
```

for the first tuples ids, and

```
newList.head._2
```

for the first tuples name.

Another option could be mapping into a map, since this looks pretty much like, what you want in the first place:

```
newMap = oldList.map{e => e.id -> e.name}.toMap
```

This way you can access members like this `newMap("key")` or safer:   `newMap.get("key")` which returns an option and wont end up in an exception, if the key doesn't exist.